# Input values in reactive forms are not fetched (Angular5)

Tags: angular

I have used reactive forms in my application. 
I am assigning the value to the input fields using interpolation.

After submitting the form, the value assigned to the input field using interpolation is not fetched. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

**main.component.html**

```html
<form  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input value={{item}} type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Item">
  </div> 
  <button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

**main.component.ts**

```js
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

   form: FormGroup;

   constructor() {
     this.form = new FormGroup({
       Item: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
     })
   }

   onSubmit(value){
     console.log(value);
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It seems there’s a bit of confusion on how reactive forms work. Why are you passing form.value on the onSubmit? The source of truth is in the component already, not on the template. And why do you need interpolation for a control of a reactive form?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```html
<input value="{{item}}" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Item">
```

Answer (score 0):

With Reactive forms you don't need to set `value="{{ item }}"`.

But where `item` variable is defined?

You could do this:

```html
<form
  [formGroup]="form"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="Item">
  </div> 
  <button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there’s a slight confusion on how Reactive Forms work.

With Reactive Forms the source of truth is already on the component, in the model, and not in the template. So whenever there’s a change in the control it will be reflected in a synchronous way in the model.

Your template should not need more than this

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="item">
  </div> 
  <button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

And then in the component

```js
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      item: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  } 
}
```

I got rid of the unneeded interpolation and the unnecessary passing of the `form` on the submit function. Also I’ve renamed the control name to `item` with lowercase because capital case should be used only in `Objects` that can be newed like `classes`.

Have a look on the [Reactive Forms documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)  to get a better idea on how they work

Comment: I had used interpolation as I was assigning some value from component to html input element. Later when submit was clicked, I wanted to pass the complete data from form back to component. But when I was trying to do this, all the data was fetched except the values of these input element which I was assigning using interpolation.

Comment: So this is where your confusion is. The data is already in the form.  Whenever you change the data in the input it will also change in the component in a synchronous way. You don’t need to pass anything up or down. If you check my solution you will see that it will log whichever value you set in the input. That’s why they are called reactive forms. Whenever you change the data in the component or in the template the form variable in the component will always be in sync. That’s the beauty of it :)

Comment: If this solution solved your problem please don’t forget to check the answer as accepted so it can help others with a similar issue.

Comment: I know that the form contains all the data. But in my case when I am trying to print the form value, all the data is fetched from the form but only the ones assigned using interpolation is not fetched by form. Why is this happening?

Comment: I still don’t understand the use case for the interpolation. Why do you need the interpolation for?